# Most general way to check if I can assign a class to another

Tags: c++, casting, variable-assignment, assign

In C++, given two classes, `a` and `b`, what is the most general way to check if some expression

```
my_a = my_b;
```

will be meaningful? I thought about using `is_convertible` but that doesn't detect a cast operator. Maybe it works only with primitive types? I would like my test to yield `true` if:

- `a` and `b` are the same
- `b` can be cast to `a`
- `a` has an assignment operator that accepts a `b` item

And so on. Is there any way to get such a thing done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`std::is_assignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable):

```
bool x = std::is_assignable<decltype(my_a), decltype(my_b)>::value;
```

Comment: @MatteoMonti that's because your conversion operator is private.

Answer (score 0):

You might check `is_constructible`, this includes casts.